# Redirect to error page in onBootstrap when a fatal error is encountered

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to redirect a user to an error page upon encountering a FATAL error. I wanted to do this redirect in onBootstrap method, like this.

```
<?php
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager   = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        register_shutdown_function(function (MvcEvent $event)
        {
            $response = $event->getResponse();
            $response->setHeaders(
                $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', "/error-page")
            );
            $response->setStatusCode(302);
            $response->sendHeaders();
            return $response;
        });     
    }
}
?>
```

However, I am getting an error saying:

```
    Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to 
MyException\Module::MyException\{closure}() must be an instance of 
Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent, none given in MyException\Module.php on line 11.
```

Is there any other way to redirect the user?

I tried this as well, but I am getting **headers are already sent** error.

```
register_shutdown_function(function ()
        {
            ob_clean();
            ob_flush();
            ob_start();
            header ('Location: /');
            ob_end();
        });
```

Any Ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e){
    $e->setError('my-custom-error');
    $event->getTarget()->getEventManager()->trigger('dispatch.error', $e);
}

    public function onDispatchError(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        // Do nothing if the result is a response object
        $result = $event->getResult();
        if ($result instanceof Response) {
            return;
        }

        // Common view variables
        $viewVariables = array(
            'error' => $event->getParam('error'),
        );

        $error = $event->getError();
        switch ($error) {
            case 'my-custom-error':
                $viewVariables['key'] = $value;                
                break;
            default:
                /*
                 * do nothing if there is no error in the event or the error
                 * does not match one of our predefined errors (we don't want
                 * our 403.phtml to handle other types of errors)
                 */
                return;
        }

        $model = new ViewModel($viewVariables);
        $model->setTemplate('my-error-page');
        $event->getViewModel()->addChild($model);

        $response = $event->getResponse();
        if (!$response) {
            $response = new HttpResponse();
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
        $response->setStatusCode(403);
    }
```